# Calculating the days of a month

Tags: ocaml

I am new to FP and OCaml.My question is how can I write a function in OCaml which will give me what day it is when entered an integer. I guess this is one way to do it but doesn't feel convenient and would need modifying for every month. Let's say the below code is for October 2016

```
let int_of_day = function
 | 1 -> "Sat"
 | 2 -> "Sun"
 ...
 | 31 -> "Mon";;
```

Which runs but gives a warning as this pattern matching is not exhaustive and 0 isn't used.
What are your suggestions to make this work better ?
Thank you already.

Comment: You can use math for this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Calendar](http://calendar.forge.ocamlcore.org/) library, available through [opam](https://opam.ocaml.org/). Once it is installed, you can have something like:

```
let date = CalendarLib.Date.lmake ~year:2016 ~month:10 ~day:18 ();;
let day = CalendarLib.Date.day_of_week d;;
```

`day` will be of enumerated type `CalendarLib.Date.day` (`Wed` in fact).

Answer (score 0):

As Gabriel noted in a comment to your code, you should compute a day of week using some formula. Here is another [list of formulas](http://katzentier.de/_misc/perpetual_calendar.htm).

What concerning the warning, then to make a pattern matching exhaustive, as OCaml requires, you need to add an all matching wildcard pattern `_`, e.g.,

```
...
| 31 -> "Mon"
| _ -> invalid_arg "must be a number between 1 and 31"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Unix.mktime which will make all calculations.

```
  let give_day y m d =
    let (_,tm)=Unix.mktime
      {
         Unix.tm_sec=0;
         Unix.tm_min=0;
         Unix.tm_hour=0;

         Unix.tm_mday=d;
         Unix.tm_mon=m-1;
         Unix.tm_year=y-1900;

         Unix.tm_wday=0;
         Unix.tm_yday=0;
         Unix.tm_isdst=false;
      }
    in
    tm.tm_wday
  in

  let day=give_day  2016 10 1 in
    Printf.printf "1/10/2016 %d\n" day ;
  let day=give_day  2016 10 10 in
    Printf.printf "10/10/2016 %d\n" day ;
```

Test :

```
1/10/2016 6
10/10/2016 1
```

6 is Saturday and 1 is Monday.

Comment: This is obviously the best possible solution but I haven't learned more than basics. Thank you very much though.